# Multiple retry PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to create a multiple verification about one variable? Like this:

```html
<?php
$name = null;

if(isset($name)){

 $name = null;
 //Ah the name is again null, let's retry 
 if(isset($name)){
  $name = "Arthur";
  //Great! The name is arthur !
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: In PHP you can override variables and check them again.

Comment: I'm not sure, how helpfull would this be to you. Php runs is single thread proccess, so it means, what you don't rewrite localy, anything else won't change it. Can you specify your intended usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the application you will give to the script, but this should do. Remember PHP will run the script first, then return the page. You cannot have an infinite loop running like JavaScript.

```
<?php

$name = null;

while (false === isset($name)) {

   // Your code in here

}
```

Comment: This way is good! But with a while can I set a variable like $name with differents values and when he found the good value he stop de while?

Comment: If it's always the same value that you want to verify, then use while ($name != "arthur")